# route is sending empty response

Tags: node.js, express, web3js

I have this controller

```
 const getBalance = async (address, network) => {
  const web3 = getWeb3Instance(network);
  const currentBalance = await web3.eth.getBalance(address);
  const formattedBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(currentBalance, 'ether');
  return formattedBalance
};
```

This is how I use it in the route:

```
 router.post('/getBalance', (req, res) => {
  const {address,network} = req.body
  try {
    res.status(200).send(controllers.getBalance(address,network))
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).send(`${e}`)
  }
});
```

When I `console.log(formattedBalance)` it logs the correct answer but in the response it is sending empty object `{}` and I don't know why. I'm using node.js with express and web3.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the word `async` infront of your function. An function has an different behaviour if you put `async` infront of it. It acts like an promise.

Did you tried `console.log(controllers.getBalance(address,network))`? In the browser you would see `Promise { <pending> }`

The problem is you sending an pending promise back.

Change it to this. You need to wait till the promise resolves

```
 router.post('/getBalance', async (req, res) => {
  const {address,network} = req.body
  try {
    let balance = await controllers.getBalance(address,network);
    res.status(200).send(balance)
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(404).send(`${e}`)
  }
});
```